# How can I install evdev on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3?

Tags: python, evdev

I'm working with Python on a Raspberry Pi using the Raspian operating system. I installed `evdev-0.4.7` and it works fine for Python 2.7. But when I try it for Python 3.3 I get an error. Apparently it only installed on Python 2.7.

How can I install `evdev` on Python 3.3 as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to install it with `pip3`

`sudo pip3 install evdev`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I did first have to do `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and then do the slightly different `sudo pip-3.2 install evdev`.

Comment: @Daanii Glad, you figured it out. Different distributions, different package names :)